# Isolated apps in kubernaties for end users

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress

I have tradional server app stack:

- database
- app (ruby)
- microservice (node)

App is avaible by https://example.com

My users wants isolated personal apps (for high availability) with full database access by connection string

So we need server app stacks:
 - personal (isolated) databases
 - personal (isolated) apps
 - personal (isolated) microservices

Apps must be avaible by http://cloud.example.com/userX, where userX is user's login

I think each user should have their own namespace. Thus, the personal database, application, and microserver belong to this namespace.

Also I have one Ingress (in namespace: kube-public) now for all users apps:

```
# ? apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1beta1
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: mgrs
  namespace: kube-public
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "nginx"
    cert-manager.io/cluster-issuer: "letsencrypt-prod"
spec:
  tls:
  - hosts:
    - cloud.example.com
    secretName: cloud-tls
  rules:
  - host: cloud.example.com
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /user1
        backend:
          serviceName: user1-service
          servicePort: 80
      - path: /user2
        backend:
          serviceName: user2-service
          servicePort: 80
      ...
```

How it is possible with Kubernetes? Maybe I need several Ingress for each users?

Maybe it is more easy make paths
userX.example.com instead cloud.example.com/userX ?

Comment: maybe it should be done here somehow without namespaces? But then it will not be completely safe. I’m confused

Answer (score 2):

One approach is use one Ngnix as a dynamic proxy to services, for that you cloud add a ConfigMap to dynamicaly rote to user service,

If you use one namespace and put the user name in the service name you should use this config:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: nginx-config-dns-file
data:
  nginx.conf: |
    server {
      listen 80;
      resolver kube-dns.kube-system.svc.cluster.local valid=5s;

      location ~ /(.*) {
        proxy_pass http://$1-service.default.svc.cluster.local; 
      }
    }
```

If you use one namespace per user and put the user name in the service name you should use something like this config:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: nginx-config-dns-file
data:
  nginx.conf: |
    server {
      listen 80;
      resolver kube-dns.kube-system.svc.cluster.local valid=5s;

      location ~ /(.*) {
        proxy_pass http://$1-service.$1.svc.cluster.local; 
      }
    }
```

Another possibility aligned with this one is to use a `Nginx-Ingress` controller and take advantages of Ngnix as ingress controller and the possibilities of apply some configuration to achieve what you wish.